# Build can not find solution

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013

I tried to configure an automatic build in Visual Studio 2013. I set `1. Solution to build = C:\Users\xxx\Source\Repos\Project\AlarmPrinter\AlarmPrinter.sln` (this is the exact path to the solution) under `BuildConfiguration - Process`. But I get following exceptions.

```
Exception Message: The project file 'C:\Users\xxx\Source\Repos\Project\AlarmPrinter\AlarmPrinter.sln' was not found. (type FileNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
Unable to restore NuGet packages. Details: The directory name is invalid
TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\a\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.
```

How can I configure the build correctly?